# How to upload screenshots to AppStoreConnect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I have submitted my app for review and I am trying to modify some of the already uploaded screenshots in my app, however, I do not see an option to remove nor add new images:

[image: cannot upload screenshots]

Existing answers say I should see a button named "Choose file", but as you can see it is not available.

I have tried going to the TestFlight build to see if options open up, but nothing is there. The app Ready for Sale app shows the same view as in the image above.

I do not have access to the old screenshots and only want to to update some, so using my `fastlane` script does not work because it would remove screenshots I'd like to keep.

Any idea how to upload screenshots from the App Store Connect UI?

Comment: Metadata such as screen shots can't be changed when the app is released or waiting for review. You will have to pull the app from waiting for review.